# Creating 3D scatter plot with different different size of scatters using ArcMap/ArcScene

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcscene, arcgis-10.7, scatterplot

I have seismicity catalog.

How do I create a seismicity with longitude and latitude in X and Y axis and depth in Z axis?

Also, how do I represent different range of magnitudes as variation is size of scatters points?

I want to show this scatter plot under a 3D representation of the topographical view of its region.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking of this as a scatterplot, you just have basic 3D point data (x, y, z) that you want to symbolize proportionally based on a fourth column (magnitude).

Take a look at this [intro page for how to work with 3D data in ArcGIS Desktop](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/3d-analyst-and-arcscene.htm), especially the sections on creating data and a scene. This is also an area where ArcGIS Pro might be better set up to work with 3D data than ArcGIS Desktop.

This documentation page shows [how to set the symbology for proportional symbols](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/map/working-with-layers/using-proportional-symbols.htm) under the normal symbology properties tab.